# Unable to fetch component using ItemId

Tags: aem

Hi Below is my code use as listener for button.

```
function(comp, evt , record, path) {
    var str=document.URL;
    var test=str.replace("http://localhost:4502","");
    var a=test.split("\.");
    var path=a[0]+"/jcr:content";
    var dialog = this.findParentByType('dialog'); 
    panel=comp.findParentByType('panel'); 
    alert("panel :: "+panel);
    var feedurl = panel.getComponent("Url");
    alert(feedurl);
}
```

**feedurl always show undefined**. Url is the itemId of widget which is hidden. Below is the dialog.xml

```
<basic
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    title="Basic"
    xtype="panel">
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <rootPath
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            fieldLabel="Target Path"
            name="./youtubepolling/rootPath"
            root="/content/dam"
            xtype="pathfield"/>
        <btnpanel
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            border="{Boolean}false"
            xtype="panel">
            <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                <connectbutton
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    localName="connectButton"
                    style="float:right;"
                    text="Connect to Youtube"
                    xtype="button">
                    <listeners
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        click="function(comp, evt , record, path) { //js code defined above }"/>
                </connectbutton>
            </items>
        </btnpanel>
        <feedUrl1
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            ignoreData="true"
            itemId="Url"
            name="./youtubepolling/feedUrl"
            value=""
            xtype="hidden"/>
    </items>
</basic>
```

Above this hierarchy is like:

`dialog` **>** `widgetCollections` **>** `tabpanel` **>** `widgetcollections` **>** `panel(basic)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [widget docs](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/widgets-api/?class=CQ.Ext.form.Hidden), `itemId` is an alternative way to get a reference to a component when no object reference is available, and is not the same as `CQ.Ext.getCmp()` which requires a unique Id.

It is also observed that, when we use `itemId`, the id is not set to the input field and instead a CQ generated Id is used. On the other hand, using the `id` property sets the given id to the input field.

Also, using `comp.findParentByType('panel');` returns an array of panels, starting from the closest panel. Since feedurl doesn't exist within that panel, it would return undefined always for `panel.getComponent("Url");`

Try modifying the JS as shown below, and use `id` instead of `itemId` for `feedUrl1`

```
function(comp, evt , record, path) {
    var str=document.URL;
    var test=str.replace("http://localhost:4502","");
    var a=test.split("\.");
    var path=a[0]+"/jcr:content";
    var dialog = comp.findParentByType('dialog'); 
    var feedurl = dialog.findById("Url");
    console.log(feedurl);
    feedurl.setValue(path);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I got the object, now i am trying to set the value property of that object by : feedurl.value=path; alert("feed :: "+feedurl.value); alert shows me the value that i want to set, but inside node its not getting set still blank.

Comment: Try `setValue()` method. Please find my answer edited.

Comment: Tried, I see in network tab parameter is going(name & value) but value property still blank for that widget.